# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred, Pytest giving an error in ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, valueerror

I am a new learner in Python and here I have try-except to catch ValueErrors and conditional statements to catch the same error as well.

```
import re


def main():
    print(convert(input("Hours: ")))


def convert(s):
    try:
        # matches := re.search(r"^(\d+)\:?(.+)? to (\d+)\:?(.+)?$", s)
        if (matches := re.search(r"^(\d+)\:?(.+)? to (\d+)\:?(.+)?$", s)) and s.__contains__("AM"):
            matchesGroup1 = matches.group(1)
            matchesGroup2 = matches.group(2).split(" ")
            matchesGroup3 = matches.group(3)
            matchesGroup4 = matches.group(4).split(" ")

            if 0 < int(matches.group(1)) <= 12 and 0 < int(matches.group(3)) <= 12:

                if matchesGroup2[1] == "AM" and matchesGroup4[1] == "PM":
                    if matchesGroup1 == "12" and matchesGroup3 == "12":
                        matchesGroup1 = "00"
                        matchesGroup3 = "12"
                    else:
                        matchesGroup3 = int(matchesGroup3) + 12
                        matchesGroup1 = "0" + matchesGroup1
                else:
                    if matchesGroup1 == "12" and matchesGroup3 == "12":
                        matchesGroup3 = "12"
                        matchesGroup1 = "00"
                    else:
                        matchesGroup1 = int(matchesGroup1) + 12
                        matchesGroup3 = "0" + matchesGroup3

                if len(matchesGroup2[0]) == 0 and len(matchesGroup4[0]) == 0:
                    matchesGroup2[0] += "00"
                    matchesGroup4[0] += "00"
                elif "00" <= matchesGroup2[0] <= "59" and "00" <= matchesGroup4[0] <= "59":
                    pass
                else:
                    raise Exception

                return f"{matchesGroup1}:{matchesGroup2[0]} to {matchesGroup3}:{matchesGroup4[0]}"

        else:
            raise Exception

    except Exception:
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I am testing it with PyTest with help of assert. But, in the last line Pytest giving `working.py:45: Exception`, `test_working.py:9:` and `working.py:48: ValueError`. Can anyone explain what it's so and how do i fix it?

```
import pytest
from working import convert

def test_convert():
    assert convert("9 AM to 5 PM") == "09:00 to 17:00"
    assert convert("9:00 AM to 5:00 PM") == "09:00 to 17:00"
    assert convert("10 PM to 8 AM") == "22:00 to 08:00"
    assert convert("10:30 PM to 8:50 AM") == "22:30 to 08:50"
    assert convert("9:00 AM 5:00 PM") == ValueError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `assert convert("9:00 AM 5:00 PM") == ValueError`
try using the following syntax:

```py
with pytest.raises(ValueError):
    convert("9:00 AM 5:00 PM")
```

The issue is that you need to tell the testing framework that you *expect* to raise an error. Otherwise it won't know whether the error it hits was deliberate or not. With the above code, pytest will now raise an error if that code *fails* to raise an exception. Not only that, it'll also ensure that the exception you were hoping to raise doesn't stop the execution of the rest of your tests.